# CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR slower than CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR

Tags: c++, memory, opencl

So I've been playing around with OpenCL for a bit now and testing the speeds of memory transfer between host and device.
I was using Intel OpenCL SDK and running on the [Intel i5 Processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/65516) with integrated graphics.
I then discovered `clEnqueueMapBuffer` instead of `clEnqueueWriteBuffer` which turned out to be faster by almost 10 times when using pinned memory like so:

```
int amt = 16*1024*1024;
...
k_a = clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, sizeof(int)*amt, a, NULL);
k_b = clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, sizeof(int)*amt, b, NULL);
k_c = clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, sizeof(int)*amt, ret, NULL);

int* map_a = (int*) clEnqueueMapBuffer(c_q, k_a, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, 0, sizeof(int)*amt, 0, NULL, NULL, &error);
int* map_b = (int*) clEnqueueMapBuffer(c_q, k_b, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, 0, sizeof(int)*amt, 0, NULL, NULL, &error);
int* map_c = (int*) clEnqueueMapBuffer(c_q, k_c, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, sizeof(int)*amt, 0, NULL, NULL, &error);
clFinish(c_q);
```

Where `a` `b` and `ret` are 128 bit aligned int arrays.
The time came out to about **22.026186 ms**, compared to **198.604528** ms using `clEnqueueWriteBuffer`
However, when I changed my code to

```
k_a = clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, sizeof(int)*amt, NULL, NULL);
k_b = clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, sizeof(int)*amt, NULL, NULL);
k_c = clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, sizeof(int)*amt, NULL, NULL);

int* map_a = (int*)clEnqueueMapBuffer(c_q, k_a, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, 0, sizeof(int)*amt, 0, NULL, NULL, &error);
int* map_b = (int*)clEnqueueMapBuffer(c_q, k_b, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, 0, sizeof(int)*amt, 0, NULL, NULL, &error);
int* map_c = (int*)clEnqueueMapBuffer(c_q, k_c, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, sizeof(int)*amt, 0, NULL, NULL, &error);

/** initiate map_a and map_b **/
```

the time increases to **91.350065 ms**

What could be the problem? Or is it a problem at all?

EDIT:
This is how I initialize the arrays in the second code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < amt; i++)
{
    map_a[i] = i;
    map_b[i] = i;
}
```

And now that I check, map_a and map_b *do* contain the right elements at the end of the program, but map_c contains all 0's. I did this:

```
clEnqueueUnmapMemObject(c_q, k_a, map_a, 0, NULL, NULL);
clEnqueueUnmapMemObject(c_q, k_b, map_b, 0, NULL, NULL);
clEnqueueUnmapMemObject(c_q, k_c, map_c, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

and my kernel is just

```
__kernel void test(__global int* a, __global int* b, __global int* c)
{
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

Comment: in the second code can you show how do you initialize k_a, k_b and k_c with a,b and ret data and where is the clFinish. If the 2 codes do different things it would be hard to help you

Comment: Sorry, the code is the same I just didn't copy everything accidentally. In the second code, I don't initialize k_c with ret because I thought that I could just read the data from map_c.

Comment: After mapping and usage, you have either to unmap, or to perform a clWrite/Read from the mapped object in order to ensure memory consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR allocates but doesn't copy.  Does the 2nd block of code actually get any data onto the device?

Also, clCreateBuffer when used with CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR and CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR shouldn't require clEnqueueWrite, as the buffer is created with the memory pointed to by void *host_ptr.

Using "pinned" memory in OpenCL should be a process like:

```
   int amt = 16*1024*1024;
   int Array[] = new int[amt];
   int Error = 0;

    //Note, since we are using NULL for the data pointer, we HAVE to use CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR
    //This allocates memory on the devices
    cl_mem B1 = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, sizeof(int)*amt, NULL, &Error); 

    //Map the Device memory to host memory, aka pinning it
    int *host_ptr = clEnqueueMapBuffer(queue, B1, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ | CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, sizeof(int)*amt, 0, NULL, NULL, &Error); 

    //Copy from host memory to pinned host memory which copies to the card automatically`
    memcpy(host_ptr, Array, sizeof(int)*amt); 

    //Call your kernel and everything else and memcpy back the pinned back to host when
    //you are done
```

Edit:  One final thing you can do to speed up the program is to not make the memory read/write blocking by using CL_FALSE instead of CL_TRUE.  Just make sure to call clFinish() before data gets copied back to the host so that the command queue is emptied and all commands are processed.

Source: [OpenCL In Action](http://www.manning.com/scarpino2/)

Comment: Sry but I can't agree with this answer. Since mapping the memory and doing a memcpy() does indeed copy the data in parallel using DMA and it should be faster. However, you can't use it in the kernel without the unmap(). Since the kernel might use a non complete copy of the buffer. Typically this can lead to artificial speed up, that is not real spped up at all, but incomplete memory copy.

Comment: Doesn't this answer confuse mapping (i.e. PCIe transactions on write to one of the sides) with pinning (i.e. page-locking, so that you never need to resolve physical page or swap-in)?

Answer (score 0):

With the right combination of flags, you should be able to achieve "zero copy" (i.e. very fast) map/unmap on Intel Integrated Graphics since there is no need for a "CPU to GPU" copy since they both use the same memory (that's what the "Integrated" means). Read the [Intel OpenCL Optimization Guide](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/ioclsdk/2013/OG/index.htm) section on memory.